# Can't install Adobe Flash plugin

Tags: software-center, package-management, adobe

Every time I am try to install Adobe Flash plug-in via Ubuntu Software center, I get the error message:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
```

I tried various commands in the terminal but I couldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you include the detailed error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a       
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try installing again.

If the above doesn't help, you can always install Adobe flash using:

> ```
> sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
> ```

<sup>Source:[Install Adobe Flash](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-adobe-flash-reader-air-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/)</sup>

Comment: Thx for the reply :) 
The first doesn't help but with the second commands it worked. 

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a repository mismatch. I've been dealing with broken packages and dependencies ever since the last Ubuntu upgrade, last night.

Which repository location are you using?

I had mine set for a mirror in Brazil (which is close to where I live). Only after I switched back to the Main repo stuff got back to normal.

```
apt-get update
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get install -f
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: thx for the reply :)